# Type Mismatch Error when filter out a Range of dates

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

After I run the code below, it completes the filtering perfectly but then returns a:

> Run-time error 13: Type mismatch

on the bolded row. I attempted to research the issue but could not find any real solution.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, pt As PivotTable, pf As PivotField, pi As PivotItem
Dim dCurrentDate As Date, dPastDate As Date

dCurrentDate = Date
dPastDate = Date - 15

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set pt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Date")

With pf
   .ClearAllFilters
   For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
      **If pi.Value <= dCurrentDate And pi.Value >= dPastDate Then**
         pi.Visible = True
      Else
         pi.Visible = False
      End If
   Next
End With
```

Comment: are you sure all PivotItems are valid dates?   Try using IsDate(pi.Value) to check to see if it is a valid date.

Comment: even if not... they just need to be numeric to be campared.. "Run-time error 13" means there is either "nothing", "null" or any object / string.. just "add watch" for `pi.Value`... while dates always are able to be compared numerical, pi.value is not... or simply put a `Debug.Print IsNumeric(pi.Value) & " - " & pi.Value` between the ``For Each...` and `If pi.Value <=...` lines (the direct window will state the item that caused the error)

Comment: All of the values are dates, except for the "blank" value it seems to pull in as well. Is there anything I can add to the code to get it to skip any blank values?

Comment: I was able to filter out the blank problem I was having by adding a `If  pi.Value = "(blank)"` as an If at the start and making the pi.value check a nested if

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue with the following code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, pt As PivotTable, pf As PivotField, pi As PivotItem
Dim dCurrentDate As Date, dPastDate As Date

dCurrentDate = Date
dPastDate = Date - 5

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set pt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Date")

With pf
   .ClearAllFilters
   For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
   If pi.Value = "(blank)" Then
   Else
        If pi.Value <= dCurrentDate And pi.Value >= dPastDate Then
             pi.Visible = True
        Else
             pi.Visible = False
        End If
    End If
   Next
End With
```